# add table for each tbody jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm learning some jquery and I have a quick question about prepend (I read jquery page already)

I have a table like this one:

```
<table class="tableholder">
 <tr>
   <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
   <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I try to do a slideToggle effect with my table like this:

```
var newContent = $('.tableholder').contents();  
$("<div>").prepend(newContent).hide().prependTo("#container").slideToggle(1000)
```

The effects execute correctly but I loose my table tags. My firebug show me this.

```
 <div>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
     <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </div>
```

I just want my table inside the div.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.contents` only get the children of the selected elements, that's why you have no `table` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `jQuery.fn.contents` only get the children of the selected element and not the element itself, you have to add it again manually :

```
var newContent = "<table class=\"tableholder\">" + $('.tableholder').html() + "</table>";  
$("<div>").prepend(newContent).hide().prependTo("#container").slideToggle(1000);
```

Comment: When I use your function partially works. instead of displaying the content of the variable it shows me the word "newContent" any ideas?

Comment: It is probably due to the fact that `.contents()` is a jQuery element and that I add some HTML code. By replacing `.contents()` by `.html()` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.wrap()`

```
 $(".tableholder").wrap('<div class="a" />')
                 .hide()
                 .parent('.a')
                 .prependTo("#container")
                 .slideToggle(1000)​
```

Comment: Yes `wrap` can work there, but the question seems to asked a wrap between `table` tags (and not `div`).